# Poor window performance when trying to set rounded region on media foundation video player

Tags: c++, winapi, ms-media-foundation

I'm trying to create a simple rounded video player using `CreateEllipticRgn` and `SetWindowRgn` functions.

```
HWND myHwnd;  // my video player window handle
IMFActivate* pActive = nullptr;
IMFMediaSink* pVideoSink = nullptr;
IMFVideoRenderer* pVideoRenderer = nullptr;
IMFVideoDisplayControl* pVideoDisplayControl = nullptr;
// create a video display
MFCreateVideoRendererActivate(myHwnd, &pActive);
pActive->ActivateObject(IID_IMFMediaSink, (void**)&pVideoSink);
pVideoSink->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IMFVideoRenderer), (void**)&pVideoRenderer);
pVideoRenderer->InitializeRenderer(NULL, NULL);
pVideoSink->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IMFGetService), (void**)&pService)
pService->GetService(MR_VIDEO_RENDER_SERVICE, __uuidof(IMFVideoDisplayControl), (void**)&pVideoDisplayControl);
pVideoDisplayControl->SetVideoWindow(myHwnd);
// ...

// message handling in my video player window
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_ACTIVATE:   
        HRGN hRegion = CreateEllipticRgn(0,0,1440,1440);
        SetWindowRgn(myHwnd, hRegion, true);
        break;  
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

This code is working fine when the window size is small, but the whole desktop becomes lagging after I increase window size over ~1000px width and height.

I also tried to create a rounded window in C# Winforms/WPF, set the video window handle to the Winforms/WPF window, and resulting similar behaviors.

In the task manager, my app takes less than 10% of CPU and GPU usage.

**Question:**

What is the bottleneck of a rounded window region, and how could I improve the performance?

Comment: @Sinatr got it. Removed the C# tag.

Comment: From the docs: *After a successful call to SetWindowRgn, the system owns the region specified by the region handle hRgn. The system does not make a copy of the region. Thus, you should not make any further function calls with this region handle. In particular, do not delete this region handle. The system deletes the region handle when it no longer needed.*

Comment: @user7860670 got it.

Comment: MF EVR is using Direct3D 9 and is legacy API, elliptic region is a part of GDI and is again legacy API. Those are supposed to work but the performance is not promised, at least in such scenario where you are overloading the APIs with load they have never been supposed to handle. To make things nice and efficient and elliptic, it would be Direct3D 11, Direct2D, custom presenter or similar.